# Error trying to run app on iOS device. It runs on emulator

Tags: ios

I'm getting a weird issue trying to load my app using ZXing on my iPhone.
It runs on the simulator, but when I tried to run it on my iPhone it says:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/....../MyApp.app/MyApp' -- No such file or directory
```

And If a look into that path the file already exist!

Why could this be happening?

Am woking on iOS 5.1 (targeting 4.0) with the last version of ZXing.

Comment: Is there any other description of the error? Does it mention architectures at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart XCode, perhaps this is the solution.

Comment: I should restart my Mac too. Thanks!